# Minimum Privileges for a Developer in SQL Report server

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, database-administration

We are trying to restrict the developer access in production report server. I am a SQL DBA and new to SSRS.

Currently developer have administrator access.
Developer Work: Just view and Run report

Can anyone suggest the kind of role to developers?

Comment: Developers shouldn't have anything but read-only access in production? Save higher levels of access for the people who are entrusted to deploy reports to production after appropriate testing has been completed and approved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the permissions in the site settings page in the security tab:

[To add a user or group to a system role](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156034.aspx):

- Start Report Manager (SSRS Native Mode).
- Click Site Settings.
- Click Security.
- Click New Role Assignment.
- In Group or user name, enter a Windows domain user or group account
  in this format: \. If you are using forms
  authentication or custom security, specify the user or group account
  in the format that is correct for your deployment.
- Select a system role, and then click OK.Roles are cumulative, so if
  you select both System Administrator and System User, a user or group
  will be able to perform the tasks in both roles.
- Repeat to create assignments for additional users or groups.

[To add a user or group to an item role](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156034.aspx):

- Start Report Manager and locate the report item for which you want to
  add a user or group.
- Hover over the item, and click the drop-down arrow.
- In the drop-down menu, click Security.
- Click New Role Assignment.

[To modify or delete a system role assignment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156502.aspx)

- Start Report Manager (SSRS Native Mode).
- Click Site Settings.
- Click Security. All system-level role assignments currently defined
  for the server or scale-out deployment are listed by account name.
- Find the role assignment that you want to modify or delete.
- To add or remove the role for a particular user or group, click Edit.
- To delete a role assignment, click the check box next to the user or
  group name, and then click Delete.

[To modify or delete an item role assignment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156502.aspx)

- Start Report Manager and locate the item for which you want to edit
  or delete a role assignment.
- Hover over the item, and click the drop-down arrow.
- In the drop-down menu, click Security.
- Find the role assignment that you want to modify or delete.
- To add or remove the role for a particular user or group, click Edit.
- To delete a role assignment, click the check box next to the user or
  group name, and then click Delete.

[Description of different roles can be found here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157363.aspx)